# Including an offset when using cph {rms} for validation of a Cox model

Tags: r, validation, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am externally validating and updating a Cox model in R. The model predicts 5 year risk. I don't have access to the original data, just the equation for the linear predictor and the value of the baseline survival probability at 5 years.

I have assessed calibration and discrimination of the model in my dataset and found that the model needs to be updated.
I want to update the model by adjusting baseline risk only, so I have been using a Cox model with the linear predictor ("beta.sum") included as an offset term, to restrict its coefficient to be 1.

I want to be able to use cph instead of coxph as it makes internal validation by bootstrapping much easier. However, when including the linear predictor as an offset I get the error:

"Error in exp(object$linear.predictors) :
non-numeric argument to mathematical function"

Is there something I am doing incorrectly, or does the cph function not allow an offset within the formula? If so, is there another way to restrict the coefficient to 1?

My code is below:

```
load(file="k.Rdata")

### Predicted risk ###

# linear predictor (LP)
k$beta.sum <- -0.2201 * ((k$age/10)-7.036) + 0.2467 * (k$male - 0.5642) - 0.5567 * ((k$epi/5)-7.222) +
  0.4510 * (log(k$acr_mgmmol/0.113)-5.137)

k$pred <- 1 - 0.9365^exp(k$beta.sum)

# Recalibrated model

# Using coxph:
cox.new <- coxph(Surv(time, rrt) ~ offset(beta.sum), data = k, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

# new baseline survival at 5 years
library(pec)
predictSurvProb(cox.new, newdata=data.frame(beta.sum=0), times = 5) #baseline = 0.9570

# Using cph
cph.new <- cph(Surv(time, rrt) ~ offset(beta.sum), data=k, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, surv=TRUE)
```

The model will run without surv=TRUE included, but this means a lot of the commands I want to use cannot work, such as calibrate, validate and predictSurvProb.

EDIT:

I will include a way to reproduce the error

```
library(purr)
library(rms)

n <- 1000
set.seed(1234)

status <- as.numeric(rbernoulli(n, p=0.1))
time <- -5* log(runif(n))
lp <- rnorm(1000, mean=-2.7, sd=1)
mydata <- data.frame(status, time, lp)

test <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ offset(lp), data=mydata, surv=TRUE)
```

Comment: Using the example code for `cph()` and adding an offset variable in works for me.  So it doesn't seem to be something about the `cph()` function that doesn't allow an offset. Without your data (or a way to reproduce the error) it is going to be difficult to help more.

Comment: Was this with other variables in the model? I have also tried with the example code for cph and it worked when other terms were included, but not when it was just the offset term. Unfortunately I can't provide my data, but I will edit the post to include a way to reproduce the error.

Comment: `cph` is from the rms package. Harrell writes very good documentation. You might need 1+offset(). Have you tried that idea?

Comment: Error. Cannot find rbernoulli.

Comment: Sorry - thought the command was included in base R. I've updated. I have tried 1 + offset but still get the same error. I'm sure it will be a quirk I am not aware of rather than an error in the package, but I just can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: @FMaher It does indeed appear to be a bug (at least in rms::lrm so I assume rms::cph as well). Please see the package author's response at https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/rms-discussions/3275/78